# NextJS server-side fetch - TypeError: Failed to parse URL from httр://localhost:3000/api/test

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, fetch, next.js13

I'm trying to fetch data from another resource in an API endpoint in NextJS (dev mode) and getting the following error:

```
error - TypeError: Failed to parse URL from httр://localhost:3000/api/test
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14152:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/checkout.js:8:20)
    at async Object.apiResolver (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:372:9)
    at async DevServer.runApi (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:514:9)
    ... 5 lines matching cause stack trace ...
    at async XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:157:99 {
  page: '/api/checkout',
  [cause]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
      at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
      at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
      at new URL (node:internal/url:645:5)
      at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6947:25)
      at fetch2 (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13315:25)
      at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:14150:18)
      at fetch (node:internal/process/pre_execution:241:25)
      at infoAPI (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/modules/reporting/api/infoAPI.js:17:12)
      at handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/checkout.js:8:100)
      at Object.apiResolver (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\api-utils\node.js:372:15)
      at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
      at async DevServer.runApi (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:514:9)
      at async Object.fn (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\next-server.js:828:35)
      at async Router.execute (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\router.js:243:32)
      at async DevServer.runImpl (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:432:29)
      at async DevServer.run (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\dev\next-dev-server.js:831:20)
      at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:375:20)
      at async XXX\node_modules\next\dist\server\base-server.js:157:99 {
    input: 'httр://localhost:3000/api/test',
    code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL'
  }
}
```

Here's the code that I'm using in `/src/pages/api/checkout.js`:

```
async function infoAPI() {
  return fetch('httр://localhost:3000/api/test');
}

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const result = await infoAPI();

  //...

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'success', data: result });
}
```

`httр://localhost:3000/api/test` is just an example. No matter what URL is provided in `fetch` - localhost or external, the error is the same. I need to call some external URLs in my app like this.

What can be wrong with it?

**Update:**

Same problem with `http.get('httр://localhost:3000/api/test', (res) => {/*...*/})` requests:

```
error - TypeError [ERR_INVALID_URL]: Invalid URL
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
    at URL.onParseError (node:internal/url:565:9)
    at new URL (node:internal/url:645:5)
    at new ClientRequest (node:_http_client:134:30)
    at request (node:http:97:10)
    at Object.get (node:http:108:15)
    at result (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/checkout.js:15:53)
    ... 
{
  input: 'httр://localhost:3000/api/test',
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_URL',
  page: '/api/checkout'
}
```

I'm running Next v13.2.4 on Node v19.4.0 (Windows 10).

Comment: Check the raised issue form next.js https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/48344

Comment: @sahedmoral This seems to be the opposite. The error there occurs when you leave out `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: There is a similar issue (TypeError: fetch failed in server component) opened in Next.js repo, some might find the discussion there helpful: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44062 (no workable solution to my problem though)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the URL was actually illegal. Sometimes invisible Unicode characters (like zero width non-joiner U+200C) can appear in unexpected places and it's kinda hard to hunt them down: https://invisible-characters.com/

Answer (score 1):

If the two links are under the same domain try to use `fetch('/api/test')` only and add a cache parameter because Next 13 keeps the cache in API `fetch('/api/test', { cache: 'no-store' })`. check this link to know more https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching.

Comment: Unfortunately, same error: `TypeError: Failed to parse URL from /api/test`. Thanks anyway.